# How can i create a new section with only 5 elements in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a PHP code that creates a team page with team member boxes on my website. The code for every team meber is fetched from the database, and it works fine, but time has passed and we are many now. So many, that I need to display only 5 team members per section. Like 5 team members in one line, the next 5 in the other line, .. - I tried a few things to do that, but I got stuck. Sometimes members were missing, sometimes he created many lines with the same members, and so on. That's why I'm asking here. I already searched a bit but couldn't find anything that helps me.

Currently, my code creates a new `<section>` for ALL team members. But that's not what I need. It should create a section for 5 members, the next section for the next 5 members, and so on. How can I do that?

(btw I'm a complete beginner in PHP and want to learn something from it so you can improve my code if you want.)

```php
function team_helfer() {
    $db = new mysqli("ip", $username, $password, $database);
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT code FROM team_data WHERE rank = 'HELFER'");
        
    $team_list = "";
    $count = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
            $team_list .= "$value";
            ++$count;
        }
    }
    
    if ($count == 2) {
        
        $code = '<section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default" style="left: 17%;">
                        '.$team_list.'
                    </div>
        </section>';
        
    } elseif ($count == 1) {
        $code = '<section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-element_type="section">
                            <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default" style="left: 33%;">
                            '.$team_list.'
                        </div>
            </section>';
    } else {
        $code = '<section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-element_type="section">
                            <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                            '.$team_list.'
                        </div>
            </section>';
    }
    
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    $db->close();
    return $code;
}
add_shortcode( 'team_helfer', 'team_helfer' );
```

Code from HTMHell's answer:```php

````
    function team_helfer() {
    $db = new mysqli("ip", $username, $password, $database);
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT code FROM team_data WHERE rank = 'HELFER'");

    $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $sections = array_chunk($rows, 5);

    foreach ($sections as $section) {
    $teamList = implode(",", array_map(function($row) {
        return $row['code'];
    }));
    $code = '<section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-element_type="section">
    <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">'.$teamList.'</div></section>';
    }
    
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    $db->close();
    return $code;```
````

Sadly that doesn't help, all elements are vanished now, i can't see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$sections = array_chunk($rows, 5);

foreach ($sections as $section) {
    $teamList = implode(",", array_map(function($row) {
        return $row['code'];
    }, $section));
    echo "<section>$teamList</section>";
}
```

Here's a live example:
https://3v4l.org/mXRtV

Comment: I tried to implement your code (see edited post) but I couldn't see any element with your code.

Comment: You're missing the second argument for [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (passing in the array).

Comment: @Razzer as M. Eriksson mentioned the 2nd argument was missing. Try again with the edited code. And a little advise: on your development machine you should turn errors ON, so you can see what's wrong, and not get stuck when things are just "missing"

Comment: The code works, but it displays now only 5 elements. The second section with the next 5 elements doesn't show up.

Comment: @Razzer look at the link I added, it works. Perhaps your query resulted in 5 rows only.